# .NET Core Google OAuth (and other providers) - do I need to store the access tokens?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, oauth

I'm unclear if I need to store and or use access tokens in this social login implementation.

I can read access token by configuring Startup.cs as below. I know that in many OAuth flows access tokens would be verified before use.

Using .NET Core's authentication framework however, I'm unclear how much of this work has already been done for me. I've looked through the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` source but this hasn't make it any clearer.

In the `LoginCallback` action below, I can read an ID for the user using:

`claimsIdentity.AddClaim(authenticateResult.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));`

So far as I can tell, this is all I need. I can store that identifier in the database and log the user in again if the ID matches next time they sign in via the authentication provider (Google, Facebook etc).

This is providing that the framework has verified the access token before I read that ID however, and this what I'm not clear on. Is the framework validating the access token before setting the values on the `AuthenticateResult` so that I can trust it has not been tampered with?

If so, I don't see any need to store access tokens.

Startup.cs

```
        services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultScheme = "Application";
            o.DefaultSignInScheme = "External";
        })
        .AddCookie("Application")
        .AddCookie("External")
        .AddGoogle(o =>
        {
            o.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
            o.ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxx";


            // Can access tokens by configuring as follows

            o.SaveTokens = true;

            o.Events.OnCreatingTicket = ctx =>
            {
                List<AuthenticationToken> tokens = ctx.Properties.GetTokens().ToList();

                tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken()
                {
                    Name = "TicketCreated",
                    Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
                });

                ctx.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        }) // Other providers ...
```

Callback handing

```
    [Route("oauth/google-challenge")]
    public IActionResult GoogleLoginChallenge(string returnUrl)
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(
            GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(LoginCallback), new { returnUrl, oauthProvider = OAuthProvider.Google })
            });
    }

    [Route("oauth/facebook-challenge")]
    public IActionResult FacebookLoginChallenge(string returnUrl)
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(
            FacebookDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(LoginCallback), new { returnUrl, oauthProvider = OAuthProvider.Facebook })
            });
    }

    [Route("oauth/microsoft-challenge")]
    public IActionResult MicrosoftLoginChallenge(string returnUrl)
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(
            MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(LoginCallback), new { returnUrl, oauthProvider = OAuthProvider.MicrosoftAccount })
            });
    }

    [Route("oauth/login-callback")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginCallback(string returnUrl, OAuthProvider oAuthProvider)
    {
        var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("External").ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (!authenticateResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("Application");

        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(authenticateResult.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(authenticateResult.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email));
        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(authenticateResult.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name));


        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> item in authenticateResult.Properties.Items)
        {
            // Read access tokens here
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> item in authenticateResult.Ticket.Properties.Items)
        {
            // or here
        }

        string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

Comment: access tokens expire after an hour on most auth servers storing it wouldnt really serve a purpose.

Comment: Yes, I've come to the same conclusion regarding storing the auth tokens. So the question I'm left with is can I trust the user id in the nameidentity / sub claim without further verification?

Comment: The sub claim is the users id on the identity server which is returning your authorization.  If its not then there is something seriously wrong with the implementation of that identity server.  sub = subject id = user id

Comment: Thanks. I'd been looking at the following piece of documentation for Google OAuth. It's clear to me now that this is warning against accepting user IDs passed from client scripts to the server. Since the above implementation is all performed on the server, it's not a concern. > https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in: Important: Do not use the Google IDs returned by getId() or the user's profile information to communicate the currently signed in user to your backend server. Instead, send ID tokens, which can be securely validated on the server.

Comment: Id tokens are a standard part of open id conect and can be verified thats what they are there for [verify id token](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token)  If you have an Id token its best to use that.

Comment: I'm expecting that the framework has already verified the tokens, but am not certain that it does, which is part of my question.

Comment: TBH I think your over thinking this.  Its a web app all this stuff is stored in the browser as cookies,  everything is verified by the framework.   What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'd disagree that verifying the internals of your authentication mechanism is overthinking things. I'm happy to trust the framework, but the lack of documentation means I don't have full confidence. As this is core to the security of the application, I've done some work in the answer below to satisfy myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wasn't clear what actions the framework was taking to verify that the user information was from the authentication provider, I set up requests from the .NET core app to go via Fiddler.

```
"environmentVariables": {
    ...
    "ALL_PROXY": "http://127.0.0.1:8888"
},
```

In the case of the Google OAuth provider, following the redirect of the browser back to the `signin-google` URI, I was able to see the framework make calls back to:

`www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`, sending the client ID secret and some other information to obtain an access and ID token.

It then calls to:

`www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/userinfo` passing the access and ID token.

```
{
  "id": "xxxx",
  "email": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
  "verified_email": true,
  "name": "Example",
  "given_name": "Example",
  "family_name": "Example",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/xxxxxx",
  "locale": "en",
  "hd": "xxxx.com"
}
```

It is clear that the tokens are short lived, so there is little point in persisting them.

The obtaining and verification of access tokens through use from server to server also looks to be secure.